# Product-like metric on a pseudo-Riemmanian manifold foliated by Lie group orbits

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Suppose we have an $n$-dimensional pseudo-Riemmanian manifold $(M,g)$ on which a connected Lie group $G$ acts isometrically (I am most interested in the Lorentzian case if it matters). Suppose that the orbits of $G$ foliate $M$.

Are there general conditions such that we can choose local flat coordinates $(x^a,y^i)$, with $x^a$ ($a,b=1,2,\cdots,k$) parameterizing the leaves of the foliations, and with the leaves of the foliation determined by $y^i = c^i$ for constants $c^i$ ($i,j=k+1,\cdots,n$), such that the metric is locally a warped product of the form
$$ds^2 = g_{ij}(y)dy^i\,dy^j + f(y)\tilde{g}_{ab}(x)dx^a\,dx^b?$$

Some motivation for the question. In general relativity, metrics of such types are often studied. For example, the Schwarzchild metric
$$ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)dt^2 + \left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)^{-1} + r^2\left(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta\ d\phi^2\right),$$
among others, is of the above type.

In general, one can show that a (spatially) spherically symmetric (Lorentzian) metric takes the form
$$ds^2 = -A(r,t) dt^2 + B(r,t) dr^2 + C(r,t)dr\,dt + D(r,t)\left(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta\ d\phi^2\right).$$
I would be very happy to see a rigorous derivation of the above fact. All of the arguments I've seen so far are by physicists and are largely heuristic. Why can we choose coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$ such that the metric takes the above form?

I am also interested in generalizations of the above fact, which is the special case of the metric in a manifold foliated by (space-like) $SO(3)$ orbits. Can it be generalized to other Lie groups? If so, how? And under what conditions?

Comment: This is already false when $M=R^3$, $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ and $G\cong {\mathbb R}$ acting via skew motions.

Comment: @studiosus Right, that's why I'm asking for conditions for which it's true. But a skew motion isn't an isometry of $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ right?

Comment: It is an isometry of course! Then I do not know what kind of conditions you are looking for.

Comment: @studiosus Is a skew motion really an isometry? You mean a "shear" when you say skew motion right? Unless my geometry is really out of date, that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: No, a skew motion is not a shear. It is a composition of a translation with rotation along the axis of the translation. If you take 1-parameter group of such motion, the orbits will be the above axis as well as some helixes.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant to say **screw motion**, not skew.

Comment: @studiosus Ah, I see. No problem. I've also updated my problem a bit. Hopefully it's clearer what I'm after now.